# phpunit : how to get the count of tests in a test directory without running test

Tags: php, testing, count, phpunit

I would like to statically get a count of number of tests in a directory. Is there something available that I can use? Phpunit seems to have a count before test runs say 0/100 and increments it as the test completes. I would like to fetch that number before hand and exit the run possibly.

Comment: I don't know whether there is such an option on phpunit. But if you want to get the simple number (without any grouping or filtering etc) you can just use normal grep to count the cases `grep 'public function test' [directory/]* | wc -l` (similarly grepping recursively if you wish to get the count from subfolders as well)

Answer (score 4):

The `--count-tests` option of [phploc](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc) can give you, just like the `grep` / `wc -l` line shown above, an estimate of the number of tests. Due to data providers, for instance, there cannot be an exact number without actually executing the tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list of tests by running the command, `phpunit --list-tests`.

To get the count, run the command, `phpunit --list-tests | wc -l`